# Can any body tell me how to detect Ctrl+C in MFC or VC++?

Tags: mfc

Can any body tell me how to detect Ctrl+C in MFC or VC++??

Is Accelerator Helpful in SDI application to detect Ctrl+C?? How?

Answer (score 2):

Add an accelerator for Ctrl-C to the Accelerator table in your application resources, and map it to a command ID. In your SDI window, handle that command ID and perform whatever action you wand in the command handler.

Comment: Do other accelerators work? If others work and it's just Ctrl-C, try handling ID_EDIT_COPY or similar - it may be you're getting some default accelerators from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The [GetAsyncKeyState Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to determine if the Control key was pressed during an event. Also the Shift key, Alt key and which one was pressed - left or right.

HTH

At the bottom of the link are more very useful links, please see them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just detect it in  OnChar method.

ctrl-c('\x03')